# If não faz comparação de Char

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

Criei no codeigniter um helper para o datatable que retornaria um html com um ícone do bootstrap.

Segue a função:

```
function trata_check($valor)
{
    $ci= & get_instance();

    if($valor=='S'){
                $html='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>';
            }
            else{
                $html='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
            }

    return $html;
}
```

A parte que chama a função no controller é essa:

```
->edit_column('diario', trata_check('$1'),'diario')
```

O problema é que a comparação `if($valor=='S')` não esta sendo feita, esta sempre retornando falso, mas quando eu mando só retornar o parâmetro passado ela retorna o valor certo, que pode ser apenas `S` ou `N`.

Comment: O problema está em como você está chamando o helper, pois o que você está passando é a string '$1', não o valor da variável $1.

Comment: Para passar o valor use aspas dupla, trata_check("$1")

Comment: Na pode ser a forma que está passando o parâmetro para dentro da função? você está usando aspas simples, consequentemente o que será passado seria o valor $1 e não o valor da variável

Comment: O valor esta sendo passado sim, tanto que se eu mandar ele apenas retornar o valor ele retorna normal, o problema esta na comparação. De qualquer forma, tentei a sugestão e não foi.

Comment: De onde vez o $1?

Comment: Ele é utilizado para passar parâmetros na função edit_colum do CI.

Answer (score 1):

A chamada da função estava sendo feita errada, do modo que estava o valor era passado, mas ficava com algumas sujeiras na memória, logo ele achava que S era diferente do valor passado.
Segue a maneira correta:

```
>edit_column('diario', '$1','trata_check(diario)')
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Dê um isset na váriavel soma, acho que irá resolver.

```
function trata_check($valor)
{
 $ci= & get_instance();

 if(isset($valor)=='S'){
  $html='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>';
 }
 else{
  $html='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
 }

 return $html;
```

Comment: Continua retornando sempre true.